# How to render individual sections in Electron desktop-class application?

Tags: user-interface, data-binding, electron

I started developing a desktop-class application using Electron, and am referring to the starter app as well as the Electron API demo app. This application has a single screen with multiple sections. Interaction within one particular section can cause other section(s) to get updated. These interactions must be in sync with an underlying model [object]; two-way data binding could be helpful here.

What is a recommended way to achieve a multi-section window with each section interacting with one another? Should I compose the layout using DIVs and CSS, or is there a library that I can use effectively with Electron? I was thinking about Handlebars or Jade but I am not sure if I need a template engine, as the entire screen is not rendered and only particular sections will be updated.

Comment: have you tried angular?

Comment: @anurupr for the two-way data binding part, Angular may be a good fit. Although I am a bit leery of using it in the Electron environment which already provides some of the desktop behavior with the help of event driven behavior (thanks to node.js). I am wondering more about how each section of the screen is going to interact with one another and how I can make the screen look like it has multiple sections.